# golang socket doesn't send all bytes before Write() method returns

Tags: sockets, asynchronous, go

Today when I try to send 100M data to my server (a very simple TCP server also written in Golang), I found that the `TCPConn.Write` method returns 104857600 and nil error and then I close the socket. But my server only receives very little data. I think it is because `Write` method works in async mode, so although the method returns 104857600, only a little data is sent to the server. So I want to know whether there is a way to set the `Write` work in sync mode or how to detect whether all data is sent to the server from the socket.

The code is as follows:
server:

```
const ListenAddress = "192.168.0.128:8888"
func main() {

    var l net.Listener
    var err error
    l, err = net.Listen("tcp", ListenAddress)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error listening:", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer l.Close()
    fmt.Println("listen on " + ListenAddress)
    for {
        conn, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error accepting: ", err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }
        //logs an incoming message
        fmt.Printf("Received message %s -> %s \n", conn.RemoteAddr(), conn.LocalAddr())
        // Handle connections in a new goroutine.
        go handleRequest(conn)
    }
}
func handleRequest(conn net.Conn) {
    defer conn.Close()
    rcvLen := 0
    rcvData := make([]byte,20 * 1024 * 1024) // 20M
    for {
        l , err := conn.Read(rcvData)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("%v", err)
            return
        }
        rcvLen += l
        fmt.Printf("recv: %d\r\n", rcvLen)

        conn.Write(rcvData[:l])
    }
}
```

Client:

```
conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "192.168.0.128:8888")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    os.Exit(-1)
}
defer conn.Close()
data := make([]byte, 500 * 1024 * 1024)
length, err := conn.Write(data)
fmt.Println("send len: ", length)
```

The output of the client:

```
send len:  524288000
```

The output of the server:

```
listen on 192.168.0.128:8888
Received message 192.168.0.2:50561 -> 192.168.0.128:8888 
recv: 166440
recv: 265720
EOF
```

I know if I can make the client wait for a while by SetLinger method, the data will be all sent to the server before the socket is closed. But I want to find a way to make the socket send all data before returns without calling `SetLinger()`.

Please excuse my poor English.

Comment: Writes are not asynchronous. What makes you think that your "server only receives very little data"? It doesn't matter how simple you think your code is, it can still be incorrect. Do include it in the question.

Comment: *"detect whether all data is sent to the server from the socket."* - Do you really want to know if all data are sent (and might be still in transit and might get lost there) or do you rather want to know if all data got received and probably also processed by the server?  My guess is the last in which case you need the server to send some kind of acknowledgement back.

Comment: Maybe related https://github.com/golang/go/issues/25722

Comment: @Peter I add my code. Please have a look. I  remain confused about the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I just want to ensure all the data is sent before Write() returns.

Comment: @alex thanks for your information. But I still cannot find the reason why my code doesn't work.

Comment: @MartinZ: sent from the application to the OS kernel, sent from the OS kernel to the network card or actually have left the computer? `Write` can only give the first, the rest is out of control of the application.

Comment: @MartinZ forget my previous message - wrong bug. You code looks fine, except your server sends received data back to the client, but your client code does not show receiving the data. With TCP connections - what comes in at one end should be read at the other end, otherwise you will have problems. And you also do not show error checking of write in the client. Do you check for write error?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks for your answer. You are right.

Comment: @alex Thanks again. The code I show here is just for reproduing the issue I encounter. In the real code I always check the returned err and there is no obvious error occurred. Just as you said, when I write some application protocols with the socket, there always are some mechanisms to check whther the server received the right data sent from the client. So I think I have got an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you poll the socket before trying to write?

Behind the socket is your operating system's tcp stack. When writing on a socket, you push bytes to the send buffer. Your operating system then self determines when and how to send. If the receiving end has no buffer space.available in their receice buffer, your sending end knows this and will not put any more information in the send buffer.

Make sure your send buffer has enough space for whatever you are trying to send next. This is done by polling the socket. This method is usually called Socket.Poll. I.recommend you ccheck the golang docs for the exact usage.

Answer (score 1):

You are not handling the error returned by conn.Read correctly. From [the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) (emphasis mine):

> When Read encounters an error or end-of-file condition after successfully reading n > 0 bytes, it returns the number of bytes read. It may return the (non-nil) error from the same call or return the error (and n == 0) from a subsequent call. [...]
>
> **Callers should always process the n > 0 bytes returned before considering the error err**. Doing so correctly handles I/O errors that happen after reading some bytes and also both of the allowed EOF behaviors.

Note that you are re-inventing [io.Copy](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy) (albeit with an excessive buffer size). Your server code can be rewritten as:

```
func handleRequest(conn net.Conn) {
    defer conn.Close()
    n, err := io.Copy(conn, conn)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. After some days of study, I realize that Golang makes the TCPConn.Write works asynchronously, what I should do is give it time to send all data to the server internally. As for ensuring all data is sent successfully, the higher level protocols can ensure it.